# How to hide posts on Facebook from specific people

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I have my parents as friends on Facebook. I want to know how can i post on someone's timeline without my parents seeing it. I mean, they won't see it on my timeline or in their news feed. I don't care if they can see it if the look at the timelines of my friends. how do i do that?

I have looked on the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [a friend list](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/204604196335128) that does *not* contain your parents, and then post to that friend list using the Audience Selector under the post box, when you make a post.